# Interpolating variable with object name

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, object, interpolation

This is the code I am wondering about. Is there anyway I could interpolate the 'i' variable to go after the body object. This would make it so on the first loop it was body0, then body1, and so on. I tried to do body + i.innerHTML but it gives out an error. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

JS:

```js
let url = 'https://poetrydb.org/random,linecount/1;10/title,author,lines.json'
const button = document.getElementById("button")
const title = document.getElementById("title")
const author = document.getElementById("author")
const body = document.getElementById("body")
const fullBody = document.getElementById("fullbody")

async function requestPoem(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let data = response.json()
  return data
}
  
button.onclick = async () => {
  let data = await requestPoem(url)
  title.innerHTML = data[0].title
  author.innerHTML = data[0].author
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    body.innerHTML = data[i].lines
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script defer src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <title>poem request</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fullbody">
        <h2 id="title"></p>
        <h3 id="author"></h3>
        <p id="body1"></p>
        <p id="body2"></p>
        <p id="body3"></p>
        <p id="body4"></p>
        <p id="body5"></p>
        <p id="body6"></p>
        <p id="body7"></p>
        <p id="body8"></p>
        <p id="body9"></p>
        <p id="body10"></p>
    </div>
    <button id="button">request poem</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please describe what you're trying to achieve with this or what problem you're actually trying to solve? You can't have multiple bodies

Comment: Not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Could you provide some example code with a desired output?

Comment: What is `body`? Is it `document.body`? How are there multiple bodies? If there actually are, put them in an array.

Comment: It's not document.body. It's multiple elements inside the div that are called body + a number. What I'm trying to achieve is to organize lines of a poem into multiple lines, I wanna do this by putting the different elements of the array in different html elements.

Comment: @pizzalawl Still: start by putting the html elements into an array so that you can loop them and/or access them by index. Please [edit] your question to include the html (or the code generating it) if you have trouble with that.

Comment: added more info to my question, sorry for the small amount of info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a crude way could look something like this:

```js
const data = [
  'Poem line 1',
  'Poem line 2',
  'Poem line 3'
];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(`body${i+1}`).innerHTML = data[i];
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p id="body1"></p>
  <p id="body2"></p>
  <p id="body3"></p>
</section>
```

but if you share more of the code you have (including the markup) there might be a more elegant solution.

EDIT Updated solution based on provided info by OP

```js
let url = 'https://poetrydb.org/random,linecount/1;10/title,author,lines.json'
const button = document.getElementById("button")
const title = document.getElementById("title")
const author = document.getElementById("author")
const body = document.getElementById("body")
const fullBody = document.getElementById("fullbody")

async function requestPoem(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let data = response.json()
  return data
}
  
button.onclick = async () => {
  let data = await requestPoem(url)
  title.innerHTML = data[0].title
  author.innerHTML = data[0].author
  fullBody.innerHTML = data[0].lines.reduce((val, cur) => {
    return val + `<p>${cur}</p>`;
  }, '');
}
```

```html
<h2 id="title"></p>
<h3 id="author"></h3>
<div id="fullbody"></div>
<button id="button">request poem</button>
```

Comment: edited my answer to have all of my code. i'll use this solution for now but let me know if there's a better solution.

Comment: Took your updated code and changed it a bit, hope it helps!